# Does gradient descent optimizer change my bias? If so, is it by the learning rate?

Tags: python, tensorflow, linear-regression

I'm trying to program linear regression without much external help and I've done it successfully to an extent since my MSE usually returns a small number and the outputted line of best fit looks about right. I just have a question about the last line of code below. Does the optimizer also change the bias, and if so, is it by the learning rate?

```
#tf graph input, the 9 training values 
X = tf.placeholder("float")
Y = tf.placeholder("float")

random = random.uniform(0,20)
#weights and biases
W = tf.Variable((random), name = "Weight")
b = tf.Variable((random), name = "Bias")

#linear model multiply x by weights and biases to get a y 
pred = tf.add(tf.multiply(X, W), b) 

#cost function to reduce the error. MSE
cost = tf.reduce_sum(tf.pow(pred-Y, 2))/(2*n_samples)

#minimize cost taking steps of 0.01 down the parabola 
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, the optimizer changes the bias and the learning is done with respect to learning rate. Optimizers update all the trainable variables in the graph unless the var_list option is set (in which case they update the variables in that list).

Comment: So the weights and biases are subtracted or added by my learning rate each step?